# Group theory, quotient groups?

Tags: group-theory

Let $G$ be an abelian group.

a) Show that $K=\{a\in G: |a|≤2\}$ is a subgroup $G$.
b) Show that $H=\{x^2: x\in G\}$ is a subgroup of $G$.
c) Prove that $G/K\cong H$ [Hint: Define a surjective homomorphism from $G$ to $H$ with kernel $K$]

My attempt at part a:

Let 
$a, b\in K$.

Then $(ab)^2 = a^2 * b^2 = e * e$ (since $a,b$ have order $1$ or $2$) $= e$,

so $ab\in K$.

Also $(a^{-1}) * a = e$, so $(a^{-1})^2 * a^2 = (a^{-1})^2 = e^2 = e$, and $a^{-1}\in K$.

$K$ is nonempty since it contains the identity.

So $K$ is a subgroup of $G$.

Is this right?

Comment: Yes, your proof of part (a) looks correct!

Comment: Its good so far, though I would rearrange the $a^{-1}$ line to read:  $(a^{-1})^2 = (a^{-1})^2 * e = (a^{-1})^2 * a^2 = (a^{-1}*a)*(a^{-1}*a)=e*e=e$.  Its a bit nitpicky I suppose, but I like to start on the left with what I want to show has a property.  Now, what are your thoughts on (b) and (c)?

Comment: Part of the question is answered [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/146896/8271). For the rest, hint: first isomorphism theorem.

Comment: Part b would maybe go something like this: Let a,b ∈ H. Then a = x^2, b = y^2 for some x,y ∈ G. Then a(b^-1) = x^2 * (y^-1)^2 ∈ G, and H is nonempty since e is in it. Right?

Answer (score 2):

Your proof of a) works. Another possible approach is the following: recall that $K$ is a subgroup if and only if $x,y\in K$ implies $xy^{-1}\in K$. First observe that for any $h\in K$ we have $h=h^{-1}$ since $h^2=e$. Take $x,y\in K$, we have
$$(xy^{-1})^2=x^2(y^{-1})^2=x^2y^2=e$$
thus $xy^{-1}\in K$.

Part b) is straight forward calculation.

Part c), define $\phi:G\to H,\phi(x)=x^2$, then it is easy to see that $\phi$ is a surjective homomorphism with $ker(\phi)=K$. Thus by first isomorphism theorem, $G/K\cong H$